# Is it possible to use the input command to enter functions in order to use numderivative?

Tags: scilab

I've been working on numerical methods to solve polynomial and non-polynomial equations. I wanted to use numderivative to calculate the defined derivative of a function entered by the user with the following simple code:

```
clc
clear 
x0 =input('Enter the x value: ') // x0 = 4
function y = f(x)
    y = input('Enter your function: ') // y = sqrt(x)
endfunction
dd = numderivative(f,x0)
printf('The definite derivative value of f(x) in x = %d is %.6f',x0,dd)
```

- The output is the following:

  Enter the x value: 4

  Enter your function: sqrt(x)

  Enter your function: sqrt(x)

  The definite derivative value of f(x) in x = 4 is 0.250000
- This code asks for the function twice. I would like to know how to solve that problem. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to enter a function, but you can enter the instructions of the function:

```
x0 =input('Enter the x value: ') // x0 = 4 
instr = input('Enter the expression to derivate as a function of x: ',"s")//sqrt(x)
deff("y=f(x)","y="+instr)

dd = numderivative(f,x0)
printf('The definite derivative value of f(x) in x = %d is %.6f',x0,dd)
```